# Random number generator for non-central chi-squared with non-integer dimension

Tags: distributions, random-generation, non-central

Does someone know of a random number generation algorithm for a non-central chi-squared distribution with a non-integer dimension?

PS By algorithm, I am interested in the detailed procedure or methodology underlying the algorithm.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "non-integer dimension"?  The function `rchisq` in `R` can generate random values from the $\chi^2$ distribution with a real positive non-centrality parameter (option `ncp`).

Comment: @utobi - ... and with noninteger shape (degrees of freedom) parameter.

Comment: `rchisq` can also deal with non-integer degrees of freedom.

Comment: Because the non-central chi-squared distribution is a Poisson mixture of central chi-squared distributions, you can easily generate random variables in a two-stage process if you can generate central chi-squared variates.

Comment: Welcome to CV, user378619. In case these are useful resources, see Devroye, L. (1986). [*Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation*](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html). Springer Verlag. (Free pdf from the author!) And perhaps, Knuth's [*The Art Of Computer Programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) Vol.2 Chapter 3 which has a wealth of commonly used approaches to generating random numbers, including from specific distributions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to generate random draws from a central chi-squared distribution, or from its equivalent gamma version; see below for the details. I also suggest possible readings on algorithms for the generation of random variates from a gamma distribution, in case this premise does not hold; see also the references provided in the comments of your post.

**Solution 1.**
As per comments, the function `rchisq` of `R` does implement what you are looking for. From the help page of this function:

> **Usage**
>
> rchisq(n, df, ncp = 0)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> n:    number of observations. If length(n) > 1, the length is taken to be
> the number required.
>
> df:   degrees of freedom (non-negative, but can be non-integer).
>
> ncp:  non-centrality parameter (non-negative).

Here is a simple `R` code for generating $10^4$ samples from the chi-square with $\nu = 2.56$ degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter ncp=6.52.

```
hist(rchisq(10^4, df=2.56, ncp=6.52))
```

[image]
**Solution 2.** Expanding over whuber's comment, you can generate numbers from this distribution by noting the fact that its density is an infinite mixture of central chi-squared distributions with Poisson weights. That is, a non-central chi-squared random variable with non-centrality parameter $\lambda$, i.e. $\chi_\nu^2(\lambda)$ has density function

$$
f(x;\nu, \lambda) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda/2} (\lambda/2)^r}{r!}f_{\chi_{\nu+2r}^2}(x) = E\left(f_{\chi_{\nu+2R}^2}\right),
$$
where $R\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda/2)$ and $\chi_\nu^2$ denotes the central chi-squared distribution.

To generate a random variate $x$ from the $\chi_\nu^2(\lambda)$ distribution then do:

- draw $r$ from $\text{Poisson}(\lambda/2)$
- draw $x$ from $\chi^2_{\nu +2r}$

Here is a simple `R` code for all this.

```
# implement a simple function 
my_rchisq <- function(df, ncp) {
  if(ncp==0)
    stop("Please use rchisq.")
  n = rpois(1, lambda = ncp/2)
  out = rchisq(1, df= df + 2*n, ncp = 0)

  return(out)
}

# call the function N times
gen2 <- sapply(1:N, function(x) my_rchisq(dof,ncp))

# draw a histogram and compare it with true pdf
hist(gen2,breaks = 30, probability = TRUE)
plot(function(x) dchisq(x, df=dof, ncp=ncp), 
n=200, 
add=TRUE, 
lwd=2, xlim = c(0,50))
```

[image]

**Comments**
The code presumes you know how to generate random variates from $\chi_{\nu}^2$, for any real $\nu>0$ (again, see `rchisq` in `R`). However, since this distribution is a special case of a gamma distribution, i.e. if $Y \sim \chi_{nu}^2$ then $Y$ has a gamma distribution with shape parameter $\nu/2$ and scale parameter equal to  2, it boils down to generating random draws from the gamma distribution (`rgamma` in R).

Since you are interested in $0<\text{ncp}<1$, this means that you have to draw from the gamma distribution with a shape parameter between zero and one. It turns out that the generation of random draws, in this case, may be troublesome due to close-to-zero values. The documentation of `rgamma` reads

> Note that for smallish values of shape (and moderate scale) a large
> parts of the mass of the Gamma distribution is on values of xx so near
> zero that they will be represented as zero in computer arithmetic. So
> rgamma may well return values which will be represented as zero. (This
> will also happen for very large values of scale since the actual
> generation is done for scale = 1.)

Now, if you also wish to know how to generate random draws from a gamma distribution, I suggest looking at the references on the help page of `rgamma`, which are specific to this issue. In particular, for the problem of shape between 0 and 1 check

> Ahrens, J. H. and Dieter, U. (1974). Computer methods for sampling
> from gamma, beta, Poisson and binomial distributions. *Computing*, **12**, 223–246.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this particular R function. I am interested in knowing what methodology they use. In your example, is it some sort of interpolation between a 2 and 3 df random number?

Comment: Many thanks. In my particular quest, I would be interested in knowing more about the case 0 < df < 1.

Comment: The methodology is explained in the help page.  After typing `?rchisq`, you can read that "The non-central dchisq and rchisq are computed as a Poisson mixture of central chi-squares (Johnson et al, 1995, p.436)."  For the case with small df, that page refers you to the Gamma distribution.  The df is half the shape parameter. `?rgamma` tells you "rgamma ... for 0 < shape < 1 uses Ahrens, J. H. and Dieter, U. (1974). Computer methods for sampling from gamma, beta, Poisson and binomial distributions. Computing, 12, 223–246."

Comment: Thank you whuber and utobi.